# What is a good game engine that uses Lua?

Tags: lua, game-engine

I know [Love2D](http://love2d.org/) and [Corona SDK](https://coronalabs.com/) (for mobile devices). Is there any other game engines that use Lua you recommend?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

### **Game engines that use Lua**

**Free unless noted**

- [Agen](https://www.2dengine.com/) (**2D** Lua; Windows)
- [Amulet](https://github.com/ianmaclarty/amulet) (**2D** Lua; Window, Linux, Mac, HTML5, iOS)
- [Cafu 3D](http://www.cafu.de/) (**3D** C++/Lua)
- [Cocos2d-x](https://www.cocos2d-x.org/) (**2D** C++/Lua/JS; Windows, Linux, Mac, iOS, Android, BlackBerry)
- [Codea](https://codea.io/) (**2D&3D** Lua; iOS (Editor is iOs app); **$14.99 USD**)
- [Cryengine by Crytek](http://www.crytek.com/cryengine) (**3D** C++/Lua; Windows, Mac)
- [Defold](http://defold.com) (**2D** Lua; Windows, Linux, Mac, iOS, Android, Web, Switch)
- [gengine](https://github.com/gogoprog/gengine) (**2D** Lua; Windows, Linux, HTML5)
- [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) (**3D** C++/.NET/Lua; Windows, Linux, Mac)
- [Leadwerks](http://leadwerks.com/werkspace/index.php?/page/products/_/tools/leadwerks-engine-r3) (**3D** C++/C#/Delphi/BlitzMax/Lua; Windows; **$199.95 USD**)
- [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/) (**2D** Lua; Windows, Linux, Mac, Android, iOS)
- [MOAI](https://github.com/moai/moai-dev) (**2D** C++/Lua; Windows, Linux, Mac, iOS, Android, Google Chrome (Native Client))
- [Solar2D (was Corona)](https://solar2d.com/) (**2D** Lua; Windows, Mac, iOS, Android)
- [Spring RTS Engine](http://springrts.com/) (**3D** C++/Lua; Linux, Windows, Mac)
- [Wicked Engine](https://github.com/turanszkij/WickedEngine) (**3D** C++/Lua; Linux, Windows 10, Windows Phone, XBox One)

**Bindings:**

- [Raylib](https://www.raylib.com/) via [raylib-lua-sol](https://github.com/RobLoach/raylib-lua-sol) (**2D&3D** C++/Lua/Others; Windows, Linux, Mac, Android, Web, Other Ports)
- [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/) via [luasdl2](https://github.com/Tangent128/luasdl2) (**2D&3D** C++/Lua/Others; Windows, Linux, Mac, Android, Console Ports)

**Fantasy Consoles:**

*Editor and games run in an emulated computer system*

- [PICO-8](https://www.lexaloffle.com/pico-8.php) (**2D** Lua; Windows, Linux, Mac, Raspberry Pi, Web Player **$14.99 USD**)
- [TIC-80](https://tic80.com/) (**2D** Lua; Windows, Linux, Mac, Web)

**Inactive/Discontinued:**

- [Baja Engine](http://www.bajaengine.com/) (**3D** C++/Lua; Windows, Mac, *No Release since Dec 2008*)
- [Blitwizard](https://github.com/JonasT/blitwizard) (**2D** Lua; Windows, Linux, Mac, *Development stopped in May 2014*)
- [Drystal](https://github.com/kidanger/Drystal) (**2D** Lua; Linux, HTML5)
- [EGSL](http://egsl.retrogamecoding.org) (**2D** Pascal/Lua; Windows, Linux, Mac, Haiku)
- [Glint 3d Engine](http://glint3dengine.blogspot.com/) (**3D** Lua, *Development stopped in Nov 2011*)
- [Grail Adventure Game Engine](http://leetless.de/grail.html) (**2D** C++/Lua; Windows, Linux, Mac (SDL))
- [Juno](https://github.com/rxi/juno) (**2D** Lua; Windows, Linux, Mac, *last commit on Friday the 13th, May 2016*)
- [Lavgine](http://lavgine.pl/) (**2.5D** C++/Lua, Windows)
- [Luxinia](http://www.luxinia.de/) (**3D** C/Lua; Windows, *Development stopped in Dec 2018*)
- [Polycode](http://polycode.org/features/) (**2D&3D** C++/Lua; Windows, Linux, Mac)

Comment: Polycode is just as much a 2D as a 3D engine, the way you're sorting these may be a bit misleading.

Comment: Marmalade quick should be on the list, it can deploy to ios, android, WP8, BB10, playbook, macosx/pc desktops, bada and lg smart tvs. It uses coco2d-x and box2d and can be extended however you like. Thats all pretty impressive in my books

Comment: Marmalade quick can not build for desktops, it's strictly mobile from what their website says. Also I asked customer support and got this:  Hi
Thanks for your email.
I will make sure this information is better presented on the website. In the meantime.
`C++`
- Android
- iOS
- BlackBerry (PlayBook + BB10)
- WP8
- Mac
- Windows
- LG TV
- Roku
`Web Marmalade`
- Android
- iOS
- Mac
- Windows
`Marmalade Quick`
- Android
- iOS
- BlackBerry
- WP8
I hope that helps.

Comment: Also BatteryTech SDK - http://www.batterytechsdk.com (C++/Lua, Windows, Linux, Android, OSX, iOS, Playbook/BB10)

Comment: You can add Defold now (King's new game engine): http://www.defold.com/

Comment: Out of all of these, which ones are the most up-to-date?

Comment: Cry engine would be the most updated.

Comment: As told by John Zwinck World of Warcraft (aka WOW) has used LUA since early versions until now.

Answer (score 7):

Heroes of Might and Magic V used modified [Silent Storm engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Storm_engine). I think you can find many good engines listed in wikipedia: [Lua-scriptable game engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lua-scriptable_game_engines)

Comment: I would say that the list is far from being complete, but is good as a start.

Answer (score 7):

I can second the previous posters enthusiasm for the Gideros Lua game engine, whilst focusing currently on Mobile (iOS and Android - Windows phone 8 is in the works), desktop support for Mac, PC (possibly Linux) is also planned for the not too distant future.

Google for "Gideros Mobile"

Answer (score 6):

There's our IDE / engine called *Codea*.

The runtime is iOS only, but it's open source. The development environment is iPad only at the moment.

- [Codea App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/codea/id439571171?mt=8)
- [Codea Runtime Library](http://github.com/TwoLivesLeft/Codea-Runtime)

Comment: if u made it for the mac, and it was 40 dollars or less, i would buy it for the mac. (I dont have an ipad.) :|

Answer (score 3):

A few more:

- [blitwizard](http://www.blitwizard.de)
- [load81](http://github.com/antirez/load81)
- [egsl](http://www.egsl.retrogamecoding.org)

Answer (score 2):

World of Warcraft's engine seems all right, and it uses Lua.  :)

Comment: Yes, but it would be really costly to reuse it in own project.

Comment: @Alexander: You didn't mention that you needed an engine for your own game. I've edited your question to make that clear.

Comment: @egarcia: That was not my question. Thank you, but I have my own Lua game engine. ;-)

Comment: Alexander didn't ask the question. It was me.

Comment: WoW engine was doesn't really "use" Lua. It's an engine built in C++ and the game was made using C++. There's a Lua extension for users to make addons.