# Corona SDK to Windows and/or Mac Desktop

Tags: windows, macos, lua, coronasdk

I'm here to ask if there's any way to deploy a Corona SDK project as a Windows Standalone like an exe and/or a way to deploy for a Mac desktop. I would love to use Corona for computer applications along with mobile which is what it's made for. If this is absolutely impossible, is there a game engine/ software that uses Lua in a very similar way to Corona but for desktop applications/games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't compile Corona SDK projects to .exe or mac applications.

Corona SDK is for mobile development only.

Click this question, it's the same as your 2nd question. You'll see  game engines that uses lua.

[What is a good game engine that uses Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053134/what-is-a-good-game-engine-that-uses-lua)

Answer (score 1):

Corona Labs have just announced exporting to Mac and Windows standalone executables as an upcoming feature. see : http://coronalabs.com/blog/2015/03/02/corona-sdk-is-now-free/